# Are the eigenstates of an operator time independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue, time-evolution

In the Schrodinger picture, are the eigenstates of an operator time independent? Is it their expectation values that evolve in time rather than the actual eigenstates?
For example, say I have an operator $\hat{A}$ with a set of eigenstates $\lbrace\lvert n\rangle\rbrace$, such that $\hat{A}\lvert n\rangle =a_{n}\lvert n\rangle$. Is it the expectation values $a_{n}$ that evolve in time and the eigenstates remain stationary?

The reason I ask is that in an introduction to the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics that I've been reading, the author discusses state vectors in the Heisenberg picture and how they relate to the Schrödinger picture. Now I know that they are related in general (for a time independent Hamiltonian) by $$\lvert\psi\rangle_{H}=e^{i\hat{H}t}\lvert\psi (t)\rangle_{S}$$ but here they consider eigenstates $\lvert q\rangle$ of the position operator $\hat{q}_{S}$ in the Schrödinger picture, such that $\hat{q}_{S}\lvert q\rangle =q\lvert q\rangle$. They then relate this to the operator in the Heisenberg picture, $\hat{q}_{H}(t)= e^{i\hat{H}t}\hat{q}_{S}e^{-i\hat{H}t}$ at an instant in time $t$, and since the eigenvalues should be the same in both pictures, i.e. $$\hat{q}_{H}(t)\lvert q,t\rangle = q\lvert q,t\rangle$$ this suggests that the corresponding eigenstates in the Heisenberg picture are related to those in the Schrödinger picture by $$\lvert q,t\rangle =e^{i\hat{H}t}\lvert q\rangle$$ where the notation $\lvert q,t\rangle$ denotes an eigenstate of $\hat{q}_{H}(t)$ at an instant in time $t$.
To me this suggests that the eigenstates in the Schrödinger picture are time independent.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've just got myself confused.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat confusingly, "eigenstates" in the respective pictures behave *exactly in the opposite way* as actual states of the system. That is because eigenstates belong to operators:

An "eigenstate" in the Schrödinger picture is time-independent *simply because it is not meant to be time-dependent*. It would be non-sensical to evolve an eigenstate of an operator $A$ that doesn't commute with $H$ in time - there is no guarantee at all that it will stay an eigenstate of $A$, this would be a useless notion!

Conversely, an "eigenstate" in the Heisenberg picture *has* to be time-dependent since the observable it belongs to changes in time, and again, if it doesn't commute with $H$, it would not act as $A(t)\lvert a\rangle = a\lvert a \rangle$ on an $\lvert a \rangle$ that isn't time-dependent.

Comment: That's what I thought for the Schrödinger case. Is it correct though to say that in the Schrödinger picture if the state vector of a system is initial in an eigenstate (or is a linear the combination of them), then it is the coefficients that evolve in time and the basis kets remain constant? I think what confuses me is that the author uses the eigenstates $\lvert q,t\rangle$ as a basis to expand the state vector onto in the Heisenberg picture, but aren't state vectors time independent in this picture? How can the basis eigenstates be time dependent? ...

Comment: ...Is it simply because the corresponding operator (to which they are eigenstates of) evolves in time, and so they must also evolve in time to ensure that they remain eigenstates of the operator?

Comment: @Will: You've confused me with your question now, too ;) You must distinguish between mere *vectors* in the Hilbert space, and between *states* that evolve according to their pictures. There are three different things here: A *state* that evolves according to the picture, an *eigenstate* of a time-independent observable that's just a vector and doesn't evolve ("eigenstate in the Schrödinger picture") and a time-dependent Heisenberg observable to which we associate the eigenvectors at time $t$ ("eigenstates in the Heisenberg picture"). The latter look like the time-evolved Schr. eigenstates.

Comment: When we are talk about eigenstates they are always get evolution on time. In Schrodinger picture this is all accounted by the evolution of the initial state. In Heisenberg picture this is accounted by the evolution of the operator that describes the observable.

Comment: @ACuriousMind   So in the Schrödinger picture the eigenstates remain constant in time, and the state evolves (does this mean that, if the initial state is in an eigenstate, or linear combination, of some operator, then the coefficients evolve in time?

Comment: ... Also, in the Heisenberg picture, is it the case that the operator evolves in time, such that at a given given instant, the instantaneous eigenstates of the operator are given by $\lvert q,t\rangle$ (is this the point, that in the Heisenberg picture, vectors in the Hilbert space are eigenstates of the operator are only so at a given instant in time and not necessarily at any other times?)

Comment: @Will: I don't understand what distinction you see between "the coefficients evolve in time" and "the state evolves in time". Coefficients are based upon expansion in a particular basis, they have no universal meaning.

Comment: @ACuriousMind   Sorry, yes I realise that, but I'm just trying to get it into my head correctly on whether the eigenstates are time independent or not in both pictures. For example, in the Schrödinger picture, would one write $\lvert\psi (t)\rangle =\sum_{n}c_{n}(t)\lvert a_{n}\rangle$ where $\lvert a_{n}\rangle$ are eigenstates of some operator $\hat{A}$, whereas in the Heisenberg picture, would it be something like $\lvert\psi \rangle =\sum_{n}c_{n}\lvert a_{n},t\rangle$, where $\lvert a_{n},t\rangle$ are the *instantaneous* eigenstates of the operator $\hat{A}(t)$?!

Comment: @Will: Yes to the first expansion, but no to the second - the l.h.s. is time-independent, how could the r.h.s. be timedependent? I think the main issue is that *eigenvectors of an operator* are **not** picture-dependent objects - given an operator $A$, they are just time-independent vectors. Writing $\lvert a_n,t\rangle$, you are really thinking about eigenstates to the family $\{A(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. None of these really "evolve in time"...but it is true that $\lvert a_n t \rangle = U(t)\lvert a_n,0\rangle$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind   Sorry, I didn't word it very well. The notation $\lvert a_{n},t\rangle$ was meant to denote the instantaneous eigenstates at a particular instant in time, such that the expansion at that particular instant corresponds to a description of the time independent state $\lvert\psi\rangle$. Apologies I keep harping on, I think I've just confused myself about it all from the notation given in lecture notes, $\lvert q,t\rangle$ and them being referred to as *instantaneous eigenstates of the position operator, $\hat{q}(t)$*, for example?!

Answer (score 1):

You already know that exist two standar ways of encodes time evolution in the operator language of quantum mechanics. You may try to combine the two description in something called [interaction picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture).  All this ways to encodes time evolution is based upon this following equation:
$$
\langle A(t)\rangle=\langle\psi|U^{\dagger}(t)\hat{A}\,U(t)|\psi\rangle
$$
Where $\hat{A}$ is the operator associated to the observable $A$ at time $t=0$ and $|\psi\rangle$ is the state of the system in time $t=0$ (preparation). $U(t)=e^{\frac{H\,t}{i\hbar}}$ with $H$ being the hamiltonian of the system.

So, first, is obviously that the ray determined by the eigenstate of $U(t)$ is independent of time, after all, is just a phase contribution. The eigenstate get some sort of evolution like $e^{\frac{E\,t}{i\hbar}}|E\rangle$, but the eigenspaces of any eigenvalue is preserved through time.

Now, in the Schrodinger picture, all the unitary operator $U(t)$ are absorbed by the definition of the state at different times.
$$
\langle\psi|U^{\dagger}(t)\hat{A}\,U(t)|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi(t)|\hat{A}|\psi(t)\rangle
$$
with this choice, the operator $A$ is independent of time. The spectra and the eigenvectors of $A$ do not depend on time as well, after all the operator is independent on time. Yes, in Schrodinger picture the eigenvectors are independent on time, but the states - and eigenstates - are not!

This is crucial. If you want a state that at time $t$ is the eigenvector of $A$ in the Schrodinger picture then:
$$ AU(t)|\psi\rangle=A|\psi(t)\rangle=a|\psi(t)\rangle
$$

We can identify the eigenvector of $A$ by $|a\rangle$, where $a$ is the eigenvalue. The eigenstate of $A$ at time $t_0$ is $U(t-t_0)|a\rangle$

In the Heisenberg picture, (my favourite one), the observables absorbs the unitary operators.
$$
\langle\psi|U^{\dagger}(t)\hat{A}\,U(t)|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|\hat{A}(t)|\psi\rangle
$$

Now, for each time, we have a different operator that describes the same observable. Is expected that two different operators has differents eigenvalues and eigenvectors. So, the eigenvectors associated to the observables change through time.

If you want an state that is an eigenstate of $A$ at time $t$ you need to take the eigenvector of $A(t)$:

$$
U^{\dagger}(t)AU(t)|\psi\rangle=A(t)|\psi\rangle=a|\psi\rangle
$$

In Heisenberg picture, define an eigenvector by $|a\rangle$ is not sufficient because we have a lot of operators associated with one physical observable at different times. We can define $|a,\,t\rangle$, mean that is an eigenvector of $A(t)$ with eigenvalue $a$.